# Why are my beans worth nothing now?

Tags: banished

I spent a while trying to produce enough beans to keep my town fed while having a surplus which I could trade for other items. At first it was fine but when a ship came in with pumpkin seeds I couldn't trade with them because my beans had a value of 0. The next ship was the same.

I am wondering why my beans are now worth nothing, I have about 4,000 in the port and I normally have about 10,000+ in my storage barns.

Comment: Some Traders simply don't want certain things, it's all about who you end up with. I think the most universally traded items seem to be Firewood, Tools and Clothes. So far I don't think I've had a trader who wasn't interested in those.

Comment: So you're saying the traders' think their items aren't worth beans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your beans have not depreciated in value; that particular merchant is simply not interested in purchasing them from you. They will show as grayed out in the trade window. If you wait for other merchants to arrive who want beans, you can trade with them.